# Flutter Web on Android Emulator gives ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH on main.dart.js file

Tags: flutter, web

My Flutter web projects runs smoothly on Desktop browsers, Physical android devices, this issue just comes up when loading Flutter web app on Android Emulator Chrome Browser or on iPhone Safari Browser.

The screen is just blank as shown in the screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG3DI.png)

The app is server using python command:
`python -m http.server`

I have tried building the app with html web renderer as well but to no avail.